# How to pass an array of histogram breaks to R.hist using RProvider in F#?

Tags: r, f#, histogram, bins

I am using RProvider with F# in VS2012. I would like to pass an array of custom histogram breaks (bin edges) to R.hist. Things are ok when I pass an integer number (see line that is commented out). Could you please help me? What is the correct way to handle function overloading in this case?

R documentation on R.hist is here (see "break" arg):
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html

A working example below:

```
let arr = [| 12.3; 12.4; 13.3; 12.9; 13.2; 13.6 |]
let breaks = [| 12.0; 12.5; 13.0; 13.5; 14.0 |]
let h_tmp = R.hist(namedParams ["x", box arr;
                                "breaks", box breaks; // <------ fails here!
                                "plot", box true; ])
let h_counts = h_tmp.AsList().["counts"].AsNumeric().GetValue<float[]>()
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What error are you getting?

I tried reproducing this on my machine with the latest [RProvider 1.1.15](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RProvider/1.1.15) and it runs without any error and produces the following results, which seems to be correct:

```
val h_counts : float [] = [|2.0; 1.0; 2.0; 1.0|]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking... I am using RProvider 1.0.13 (allright, I'll do the update)... I executed the code reported above in the .fsx shell and it works fine. It gets me the histogram correctly. The result is the same as yours. However it fails when I use the function that creates the histogram in Excel via ExceDNA...

Comment: All right... it works in Excel DNA as well. However the code I reported above is a simplification of the real problem. Thanks for helping to find out. The problem is somewhere else apparently. I'll have a closer look. It is failing for other reasons. I close the thread.